# Android: how to query for the document files in android

Tags: android, android-cursor, mediastore

I am trying to list all the document files(.doc,.docx,.pdf,.xml,.java,etc) other than image, songs and video files.

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
            + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);
```

This is the query which i used. This query is returning too many files which contain images and other non readable files. Is there an efficient way to retrieve all the document files from android other than checking the file names for predefined extensions?

Comment: Search based on MIME type.

Comment: @CommonsWare: MIME type of each file type( pdf, doc, docx, xml, java, ppt,pptx) will be different. MIME based search to list all the files will require search based on each individual MIME types. Will it not become inefficient ?

Comment: I suspect that it will be more efficient than your current approach (retrieving pretty much everything, then filtering by MIME type on the client side).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare... I will give a try with that approach